# Can't access slides from other slides in Microsoft PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm relatively new to VB, what I'm trying to do is loop through shapes on every slide which is activated by an ActiveX button on the first slide, but on trying to initiate the for loop for Slide2, it returns an "Object required" error.

I'm using Microsoft PowerPoint 2018 and the built in Visual Basic editor.

```
Private Sub DisableNavArrows_Click()
    If Slide1.DisableNavArrows.Caption = "Disable arrow buttons (RECOMMENDED)" Then
        Slide1.DisableNavArrows.Caption = "Enable arrow buttons (NOT RECOMMENDED)"
        For Each oshp In Slide1.Shapes
            If oshp.Name = "ArrowRight" Then
                oshp.Visible = False
            ElseIf oshp.Name = "ArrowLeft" Then
                oshp.Visible = False
            End If
        Next oshp

        For Each oshp In Slide2.Shapes
            If oshp.Name = "ArrowRight" Then
                oshp.Visible = False
            ElseIf oshp.Name = "ArrowLeft" Then
                oshp.Visible = False
            End If
        Next oshp

        For Each oshp In Slide3.Shapes
            If oshp.Name = "ArrowRight" Then
                oshp.Visible = False
            ElseIf oshp.Name = "ArrowLeft" Then
                oshp.Visible = False
            End If
        Next oshp

        For Each oshp In Slide4.Shapes
            If oshp.Name = "ArrowRight" Then
                oshp.Visible = False
            ElseIf oshp.Name = "ArrowLeft" Then
                oshp.Visible = False
            End If
        Next oshp

        For Each oshp In Slide5.Shapes
            If oshp.Name = "ArrowRight" Then
                oshp.Visible = False
            ElseIf oshp.Name = "ArrowLeft" Then
                oshp.Visible = False
            End If
        Next oshp

        For Each oshp In Slide6.Shapes
            If oshp.Name = "ArrowRight" Then
                oshp.Visible = False
            ElseIf oshp.Name = "ArrowLeft" Then
                oshp.Visible = False
            End If
        Next oshp
    Else
        Slide1.DisableNavArrows.Caption = "Disable arrow buttons (RECOMMENDED)"
        For Each oshp In Slide1.Shapes
            If oshp.Name = "ArrowRight" Then
                oshp.Visible = True
            ElseIf oshp.Name = "ArrowLeft" Then
                oshp.Visible = True
            End If
        Next oshp

        For Each oshp In Slide2.Shapes
            If oshp.Name = "ArrowRight" Then
                oshp.Visible = True
            ElseIf oshp.Name = "ArrowLeft" Then
                oshp.Visible = True
            End If
        Next oshp

        For Each oshp In Slide3.Shapes
            If oshp.Name = "ArrowRight" Then
                oshp.Visible = True
            ElseIf oshp.Name = "ArrowLeft" Then
                oshp.Visible = True
            End If
        Next oshp

        For Each oshp In Slide4.Shapes
            If oshp.Name = "ArrowRight" Then
                oshp.Visible = True
            ElseIf oshp.Name = "ArrowLeft" Then
                oshp.Visible = True
            End If
        Next oshp

        For Each oshp In Slide5.Shapes
            If oshp.Name = "ArrowRight" Then
                oshp.Visible = True
            ElseIf oshp.Name = "ArrowLeft" Then
                oshp.Visible = True
            End If
        Next oshp

        For Each oshp In Slide6.Shapes
            If oshp.Name = "ArrowRight" Then
                oshp.Visible = True
            ElseIf oshp.Name = "ArrowLeft" Then
                oshp.Visible = True
            End If
        Next oshp
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What are `Slide1`, `Slide2`, etc.?

Comment: Unrelated, but you've got 6 pairs of `For` loops which differ only in the `Slide` object that they iterate over. Consider an outer loop `For Each s In Slides`.

Comment: @jsheeran - I'd say that's very related lol.

Comment: I'll try that Jsheeran.

Comment: Bigben they're just the slides you get, there's no get method for them which is weird, you can just modify them with their slide name. (Afaik)

Comment: "Object required" means that there is no object on slide 2 that is named either "ArrowRight" or "ArrowLeft".

Comment: @JohnKorchok they are both in the selection pane so it can't be that

Comment: When the error message appears and you click on the Debug button, a line of code will be highlighted. Which line is it?

Comment: `For Each oshp In Slide2.Shapes` @JohnKorchok

Comment: Are you certain the Slide2 is called Slide2?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend rewriting the code in loops, not relying on the slide name:

```
Private Sub DisableNavArrows_Click()
    Dim oSlide As Slide
    Dim oShape As Shape
    If Slide1.DisableNavArrows.Caption = "Disable arrow buttons (RECOMMENDED)" Then
        Slide1.DisableNavArrows.Caption = "Enable arrow buttons (NOT RECOMMENDED)"
        For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
            For Each oshp In Slide1.Shapes
                If oshp.Name = "ArrowRight" Then
                    oshp.Visible = False
                ElseIf oshp.Name = "ArrowLeft" Then
                    oshp.Visible = False
                End If
            Next oshp
        Next oSlide
    Else
        Slide1.DisableNavArrows.Caption = "Disable arrow buttons (RECOMMENDED)"
        For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
            For Each oshp In Slide1.Shapes
                If oshp.Name = "ArrowRight" Then
                    oshp.Visible = True
                ElseIf oshp.Name = "ArrowLeft" Then
                    oshp.Visible = True
                End If
            Next oshp
        Next oSlide
    End If
End Sub
```